# Regular solids and $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

The mapping from the regular solids to $\mathbb{Z}_5$ given by the number of faces in the solid mod 5, interestingly, is a bijection.  Any geometers or algebraists know if there is a significant reason for this? I mean, the fact that it is a *possibility* (i.e. that there are exactly 5 regular solids) is a well known proof, but why is this particular mapping bijective?  Just seems too much of a coincidence.

Its been 40 years since I understood the proof in grad school, and it's long since gone from my memory - perhaps this fact is even buried in the proof? Any grad students fresh off understanding the proof?

Following on comments below, more generally in $\mathbb{R}^n$, if there are $k$ regular polytopes, and we look at the mapping from these regular polytopes to $\mathbb{Z}_k$ given by $f|k$ ($f$ modulo $k$) where $f$ is the number of faces in the polytope, then (if comments below are correct), the mapping is a bijection iff $n=3|6$ or $n=5|6$. And so the question is, is there a deep reason for this?

Comment: Probably the most significant reason is the sets have the same cardinality.  There has to be some bijection, let it be this one.

Comment: Maybe it would be more interesting if you had a similar phenomenon for the regular solids in $\mathbb R^n$ for all $n$ ?  You get a similar correspondence for $n=2$, but not $n=4$ (where there are six).

Comment: Yes, there are 5! bijections, that is pretty trivial.  But a bijection that selects such a fundamental (integer) property of the polyhedra, and then maps to $Z_5$ using the most basic, obvious of maps, namely mod 5, is too much of a coincidence.

Comment: I think this question is potentially interesting. The classification of regular polyhedra is related to other classifications like of simple Lie algebras, etc., and so it’s not impossible to imagine a somewhat deep reason for this face-counting bijection to work.

Comment: The observation holds only in odd dimensions. If $n \ge 5$, there are only three regular polytopes in dimension $n$, the hypercube with $2n$ faces, the hyperoctahedron with $2^n$ faces, the simplex with $n+1$ faces. The numbers $n$, $2n$ and $n+1$ are different modulo 3 if and only if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Kepler tried to match the five Platonic solids to the five spaces between the six planets that were known in his day. It didn't end well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterium_Cosmographicum

Comment: I'm tempted to say there might be something about the Euler characteristic that helps here. The number of faces is 2 + E - V, and having the mod 5 count of faces be an injective function is the same as saying the difference E - V is an injective function mod 5. This is then a fact about the underlying edge graph, and regularity means the degree D of the vertices to be constant. Then E = DV/2, so that we are left with considering the function V(D/2 - 1). 2 is invertible mod 5, so we are considering the function V(D - 2). We know 1≤D-2≤3 and V≥4 from elementary considerations.

Comment: Not sure any of that is useful, but you really might just be running into a small-number phenomenon. Or perhaps the regular graph description (instead of face counting) in higher dimensions does something.... I can't check right now.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan : You made a slight mistake: you changed $2^n$ to $n$. So for $n\ge5$, if what you say is true and there are only three regular polytopes with the number of faces given by $2^n$, $2n$ and $n+1$, then these are distinct modulo 3 if and only f $n$ is odd and NOT 1 modulo 3 (i.e. $n\ne1|3$).  Thus, my observation seems to hold true for all $n=3|6$ or $n=5|6$ (using the notation $|$ for "modulo"). But I can't say about $n=4$ without knowing more.

Comment: @RyanBudney : Sorry, I missed Ryan's comment above about $n=4$.  Ryan, what are the regular polytopes in $n=4$? And in reply to your comment, see Christophe Leuridan's comment above and my correction above for other cases then.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_4-polytope  But in short, there's the simplex(pentachoron), the cube (sometimes called the octachoron or 8-cell), the dual of the cube (hexadecachoron or 16-cell) then there's the dual pair of the 600-cell and 120-cell, and lastly there's the self-dual 24-cell.

Comment: Arrg, seems this should be on math.stackexchange not mathoverflow??

Comment: Fwiw, the smallest modulus $m$ such that numbers of faces of regular 4-polytopes  are all distinct mod $m$ is $21$; the smallest prime such modulus is $29$

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh I've voted to move the question.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : lol. This question arose because of my (intentionally) comical attempt to map the 5 regular solids (models of which are sitting on the mantle, made from my kids' magnetic toys) to the 5 possible "topologically" unique train track layouts made with exactly two Y connectors. Interesting problem to prove there are exactly 5, and then classify all infinite train paths around each layout according to various properties.